# File Rename within same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to rename a file and keep in same dir.

```
for file in os.listdir( srcpath ):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.csv'):
        print('File Match',file)
        fixed = file.replace(file, file[:-12]+'.csv')
        os.rename(file, fixed)
```

> File Match, I_AM_A_TEST_20190401.CSV
>
> ERROR = FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the
>   file specified: 'I_AM_A_TEST_20190401.CSV' -> 'I_AM_A_TEST_.csv'

The file I_AM_A_TEST_20190401.CSV exists in dir.